# What does cv2.resize() do if input width and height same as resize input and width?

Tags: python, opencv

I like fast, compact code so I have a question about this:

```
def loader(input_path, new_img_width, new_img_height):
    input_image = tifffile.imread(input_path)
    input_image = cv2.resize(input_image, (new_img_width, new_img_height),
                           interpolation=cv2.INTER_NEAREST)
    return input_image
```

Do I need to add a conditional statement before the call to `cv2.resize` for the case where `new_img_width` and `new_img_height` are the same as in `input_image` or this conditional statement already in the `cv2.resize` code?

I don't want spend cycles resizing the image unless it's necessary.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [source code of resize function](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/imgproc/src/resize.cpp), line 4082:

```
if (dsize == ssize)
{
    // Source and destination are of same size. Use simple copy.
    src.copyTo(dst);
    return;
}
```

Comment: So I'd better have a guard statement if I don't want an unnecessary copy.

Comment: Yes, seems like resize function always returns a new Mat object.